# Styling a post-link form inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my app I have situations where I need to use what I and some frameworks call a "post-link". Basically a link that might be used to delete (or post) data with it and as such must actually be a a form.

I'm using bootstrap as my base css and have assigned the `link` class to the submit button to give it a link appearance. When using in a table with another, ordinary, `<a>` tag next to it I can't seem to get the two links to align alongside each other, no matter how wide I make the viewport or table cell.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/miocene/dbTqC/670/ I'm referring to the pencil and cross icons as my normal link and post-link.

Any ideas how I can get them to align side-by-side?

Comment: It's not clear from your fiddle what you are trying to align with what.

Comment: @harryg: Check the fiddle in my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to define a width for the `td` or use this. I gave the div in the td a class `.lol`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/dbTqC/672/)**

```
        <td>
            <div class="btn-toolbar inline lol">BLAH BLAH</div>
        </td>
```

---

```
.lol *{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.lol .btn{
    padding:2px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the float left seems to fix it. Thanks